# Troubleshooting Media helper - player stuck on loading gif

Tags: jquery, fancybox, helper

i've been making a media helper fancybox gallery, but i'm having problems... I think the console is working and all the scripts are present, the only problem is that when the thumbnail is clicked the only thing that appears is the loading button.

This is my HTML with the Java scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>


<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->


<title>Video</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
         openEffect: 'none',
         closeEffect: 'none',
         helpers: {
             media: {}
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

And my HTML tag:

```
<li><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://vimeo.com/35988604"><img src="Images/Galerie_Images/Video/thumbnails/2.png" width="100px" height="80px"/></a></li>
```

Any help will be very apreciated!!!

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: no, checked in jsfiddle and there were one...

Comment: And what was the one? Can we have a link to the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mwKpT/

Comment: I had to update the fiddle as you can't load external resources like that (it was a reference to the resource on your local machine): http://jsfiddle.net/mwKpT/1/  Works fine though.

Comment: its so weird... it does work on fiddle but when i check it on my website it just has this loading gif turning and the picture neer comes up... any ideas?

Comment: OK. do you know how to use the Firebug/Chrome dev tools Console? Or, do you have a live link to the site?

Comment: Your forked jsfiddle working perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/PEVSF/ check that you have the correct references to the fancybox js and css files

Comment: Clorckwell: No, i never used the Firebug/chrome dev tools Console. And the site isn't online yet...

JFK: I did all the references to the JS and CSS files again but it still doesn't work, can it be something with the JS file itself? i mean there is a connection to the scripts but it just look like it gets stuck...